# How to add steps to Angular Material slider

Tags: angular-material

Is it possible to show the steps underneath the slider? You can set the amount of steps easily, but we want to see it underneath it like:

--------O------------------------

1       2      3      4       5.....

This is the slider I'm talking about
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is this feature is not implemented, but have you seen md-discrete?

Otherwise I could recommend https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider.

Comment: I didn't know about either of those, thanks for the suggestions